# How to get the two pop up windows at a time using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How to create two pop up windows at the same time after clicking the anchor tag

```
$("body").on("click", ".tasks_link", function() {

  var file_number = $(this).attr("file_number");

  var pop_up_link = 'file_history.php?file_number=' + file_number;

  var pop_up_link1 = 'change_file.php?file_number=' + file_number;

  window.open(pop_up_link, "_target", "toolbar=no, resizable=yes, top=100, left=150, width=1100, height=500");

  window.open(pop_up_link1, "_target", "toolbar=no, resizable=yes, top=100, left=150, width=1100, height=500");

});
```

I tried this , but I am getting only one pop up window that is **change_file.php** . I'm not getting the first pop up window. How to get the two pop up windows at a time?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Your code is fine.</strike>

*What is happening is your browser blocking the second pop-up. In Chrome, look at the right of the address bar, there should be a "popups blocked" icon/notification*

**The problem is the second argument for `window.open`- It has to be a unique name otherwise it reopens the new page in the existing popup. See this quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) docs:**

> If a window with the name already exists, then strUrl is loaded into
>   the existing window. In this case the return value of the method is
>   the existing window and strWindowFeatures is ignored. Providing an
>   empty string for strUrl is a way to get a reference to an open window
>   by its name without changing the window's location. To open a new
>   window on every call of window.open(), use the special value _blank
>   for strWindowName.

Comment: sorry, but there is no popups blocked icon at the right of the adress bar..

Comment: I edited the answer and tested with your example, appears to work. Fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ud6m3ege/)